# Creating ArrayList by using ArrayList constructor by passing Collection as an argument

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I am learning collection framework. I am going through List Interface and one implementation of List interface is ArrayList.

There are four constructor is present in the Arraylist class to create the ArrayList object.

```
ArrayList(Collection c)

ArrayList<E> NameOfArrayList = new ArrayList<E>(collectionName);
```

My Question :

Q) I am not able to understand if we create an arraylist object by using above constructor what will be the internal flow?

Q) If we create arraylist object by using this constructor, do we putting one arraylist into another arraylist on a specific index? Really getting confuse on this?

Comment: if anybody can explain me the flow in diagrammatic representation, it will help me understand better. Please give me complete clarity on this.

Comment: The contents of the collection are copied into the new list.

Comment: what do you mean by content of collection?

Comment: What do you understand a collection to be?

Comment: Well for ex. if iam creating an ArrayList as:  ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>(); . Well if i create another arrayList as : ArrayList<Integer> al1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(al); .So it means the content of collection. Is my assumptions correct?

Comment: What assumptions? I don't understand what you want explaining

Comment: Try it and see. Note there's source available.

Comment: link to source code: [OpenJDK-11](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java); [OpenJDK-8](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably used to languages like Javascript or C++ or Scala, where you can declare and populate a collection with literal elements in a single line. Java's collections framework doesn't have this feature (frameworks like Guava can fill the gap though).

```
List< Integer > liFoo = new ArrayList<>();
liFoo.add( 6 ); // liFoo contains one element
liFoo.add( -499 ); // liFoo now contains two elements

List< Integer > liBar = new ArrayList<>( liFoo );
// liBar contains the same two elements as liFoo, in a new list
```

Comment: Thank you @Judge Mental  for giving me so much clarity on this. Got complete Clarity.